# Plot polygon's attribute on R

Tags: r, polygon, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, spatial-database

I have created a settlement plan on ArcGIS Pro, on which every polygon corresponds to a specific room in the settlement. All the polygons/rooms have some features (E.g. Fire Place, Bench etc.). I have extracted a csv file where all attributes and X and Y information is stored.

What I want to do is to plot in R only some of the rooms according to their features (E.g. only the rooms with a fire place).

Here is my initial code:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\myrtos")
getwd()
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(Rcpp)
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
rooms <- readOGR (dsn="shp", layer="rooms")
rooms <- as(rooms,"owin")
roomattr <- read.csv (file="rooms.csv", header=TRUE)
coordinates(roomattr) <- ~XCoord+YCoord
```

I tried to plot something like this, but apparently didn't work, there was no error message, but when I plotted the data there was nothing on the screen

```
constructions <- roomattr[which(roomattr$Rooms_csv.Bench == 'Yes'& roomattr$Rooms_csv.Platform == 'Yes'& roomattr$Rooms_csv.Ledge == 'Yes' & roomattr$Rooms_csv.Slab == 'Yes'),names(roomattr) %in% c("XCoord","YCoord")]
pppconstructions <- ppp(x =coordinates(constructions)[,1], y =coordinates(constructions)[,2], window=rooms)
```

I also tryied combining the files `rooms = cbind(rooms, roomattr)` and then plotting it `plot(rooms[rooms$Rooms_csv.Stairs=="Yes",])`

This method works only if I haven't run the `rooms <- as(rooms,"owin")` first.
If I have run it I get the error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 966, 84
```

The thing is that I need rooms shape file as window of analysis for plotting the rest of my data (points)

Is there any way to make it work?

I am also attaching [a link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11sRtApvnZr3nbBGFcR7R898RUYDQu_Mn?usp=sharing) of the data (csv and shp file)

Comment: What didn't work? Did the code run and not do what you thought or did it give an error message? What does your data look like? What does `summary` of it show? What R packages have you got attached? Where did the `ppp` function come from? Please edit your question and give more fuller details so we can understand and help you.

Comment: You are totally right! I added some more information.

Comment: Instead of an image of the data file, could you either make it shareable via a cloud service like Dropbox or Google Drive, or at least put a few rows into the question **as text** so we can make a data frame like it easily? We probably also need the shapefile that `rooms` came from otherwise we can't try and plot it.

Comment: With the sample data you give, there are no rows in your data that match the condition, so the number of rows in `constructions` is zero. Is that your problem?

Comment: Also, `roomattr` wont have `XCoord` and `YCoord` columns once you've converted it to `sp` class with `coordinates(roomattr) <- ....` which you seem to be trying to extract from it. They're dropped because they are now in the special coordinate info.

Comment: Yes, it is zero. I used this function, because it was the one I used for points shape files and it was working. How can I plot specific polygons according to their attributes?

Comment: What you've not explained, and what I think I've just guessed, is that `room` and `roomattr` refer to the same entities (some rooms) **and in the same order**. Now before you turn your `rooms` into a `ppp` object you can add the attributes to it like its a data frame: `rooms = cbind(rooms, roomattr)` and then select using standard R subsetting: `plot(rooms[rooms$Rooms_csv.Stairs=="Yes",])`. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, rooms and roomattr should contain the same information. The problem is that when I try to combine and plot it this way I get the error that arguments imply differing number of rows: 966, 84; and I don't really know why is that. On ArcGIS my shp file has 84 rows

Comment: Instead of commenting, you need to edit your question to show what code led to what error message, giving all the code and the error message details. Now we have your data we should be able to reproduce this.

Comment: I edited, explaining what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Select the polygons you want first from the augmented `rooms` object, then create an `owin` with the subset.

```
> roomattr <- read.csv (file="rooms.csv", header=TRUE)
> rooms = cbind(rooms, roomattr)
```

Now we have `rooms` with all the polygons and attributes. Suppose we only want the "stairs" rooms, then:

```
> stairs = rooms[rooms$Rooms_csv.Stairs=="Yes",]
```

That's the subset of stairs only. There's...

```
> nrow(stairs)
[1] 11
```

eleven of them. Want to use `spatstat` so need to make an `owin`? Do that:

```
> stairwin = as(stairs, "owin")
> plot(stairwin)
```

[image]

Comment: One more question to that. I want to plot only some of the rooms (E.g. R81 and R82). I tried this:  ` rr = rooms[rooms$rooms.Rooms =="R81" , rooms$rooms.Rooms == "R82"]
rr <- as(rr,"owin")
plot(rr)` But I only get R81 and not the second one. I also tried to put a "&" between the two variables but it din't work again. Any idea?

Comment: You might try `rr = c(rooms[rooms$rooms.Rooms =="R81" , rooms$rooms.Rooms == "R82"])`

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I would geo join with `{tigris}` and an example of filtering with `{tmap}`. I'm interested to hear what others have to say about these methods:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tigris)

#read in data
rooms <- st_read(file.path("rooms.shp"))
rooms.csv<-read.csv(file="rooms.csv",header=TRUE)

#rename index column in csv to match that in shapefile
colnames(rooms.csv)[3]<- c("Rooms")

#perform geo join of csv and shapefile
rooms.join<-geo_join(rooms,rooms.csv,by="Rooms",how = "left")

#interactive map
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(dplyr::filter(rooms.join,Rooms_csv.Stairs=="Yes"))+tm_polygons()

#static map
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(dplyr::filter(rooms.join,Rooms_csv.Stairs=="Yes"))+tm_polygons()+tm_layout("Rooms with Stairs")
```

[image]